# Как "запарсить" данную запись в MongoDB C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

Есть такая запись в БД:

```
"a": {
    "pupils": {
      "a": {
        "ticket": "Билет 2",
        "passed": true,
        "rezult": 1,
        "passed_tickets": [
          "Билет 3",
          "Билет 2",
          "Билет 2"
        ],
        "repass": false
      }
    },
```

Что нужно исправить в этом методе, чтобы не выдавало ошибку

> Element 'a' does not match any field or property of class test.Group

Скажу сразу: оба элемента будут неизвестны программе, они будут иметь разные названия.

```
coll1 = database.GetCollection<Group>("pupils");
List<Group> poop = await coll1.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync();


public class Group
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Pupils> group { get; set; }
}
public class Pupils
{
    public Dictionary<string, Pupil> pupils { get; set; }

}
public class Pupil
{
    public Dictionary<string, Info> pupil { get; set; }
}

public class Info
{
    public string Ticket { get; set; }
    public bool Passed { get; set; }
    public int Result { get; set; }
    public string[] PTickets { get; set; }
    public bool Repass { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `public Dictionary<string, SuperClass> test {get; set;}` и класс `public class SuperClass { public string test {get; set;} }`. То есть, у вас первый `Test` это не класс, а словарь, который имеет ключ (ваш `а`) и некий объект со свойством внутри.

Comment: Уже делал так, просто запись в бд более сложная, чем я указал, надеялся на другие варианты.

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос, со всеми актуальными данными. Не хотелось вставлять их изначально, т.к. думал, что будет достаточно мороки, чтобы прочитать это, упростил, чтобы было проще.

Comment: Я считаю неуважением, когда человек стучится во все доступные контакты, лишь чтоб напомнить о себе и получить ответ. Вот у меня сейчас процесс переезда, как думаете, кто на первом месте у меня, вы, или моя семья? Касательно вопроса, я сужу конечно со стороны парсинга JSON, а не базы, но даже если так глянуть, то у вас нарушена структура, прочитайте внимательно мой первый комментарий. Где у вас название динамичное - там словарь, а где нет - класс со свойством, вот смотрим на `pupil` - вы видите где-либо в JSON такое название? Я нет. Так зачем класс `Pupil`? Сразу словарь берите, без класса.

Comment: Извиняюсь, просто необходимо срочно сделать это задание, а я остановился на моменте с парсингом.